# How to solve this simple integral with substitution and partial fraction decomposition

Tags: integration

This is the question:

$$\int \frac{e^{4t}}{(e^{2t}-1)^3} dt$$

This is my solution:
$$\ln |e^{2t} - 1| - \frac{2}{e^{2t} - 1} - \frac{1}{2(e^{2t}-1)^2} $$

Which I got by first substituting $u = e^{2t}$ so $du = 2e^{2t}dt$ so

$$\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{u^2}{(u-1)^3} du $$

Then solving the system
$$u^2 = A(u-1)^2 + B(u-1) + C$$

My solutions manual takes the same approach, but somehow has a $u$ instead of a $u^2$ everywhere, and eventually ends up with something quite different.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: @G.C. I do have it in there, hence the 1/2 on the integral there. Maybe I'm misunderstanding though...

Comment: You are not missing the $\frac{1}{2}$. You are, however, overcorrecting by a factor of $e^{2t}$ by not accounting for $du$; that is, your integral should be $\int \frac{u}{(u-1)^{3}}du$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot $du=2e^{2t}dt$, thus $dt=\dfrac{du}{2u}$. There you have the missing $u$.

Comment: I accounted for it though, the integral is multiplied by a half in my question, and $2u$ is not $u^2$ anyway. I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: After the substitution you should get $\displaystyle\int\frac{u^2}{(u-1)^3}\dfrac{du}{2u}=\frac12 \int\frac{u}{(u-1)^3}du$.

Comment: I see it now, thanks for your patience

Comment: No problem.${}$